# Bluetooth support of 2 headphones

Tags: bluetooth

I need to feed two headphones from one audio source. In the past, I've done this with one of the many Bluetooth transmitters that support two headphones. I assume the transmitter did this by simply opening two Bluetooth connections, perhaps by using two Bluetooth chips.

My transmitter has recently broken, so it's time to buy another. I've seen various opinions on whether Bluetooth 5 has a new protocol feature that supports two headphones. If true, I'll look at transmitters supporting that feature. Presumably, since the protocol would be affected, I would also need new compatible headphones.

If anyone has definitive information on Bluetooth 5 support for two headphones, I'd like to see it. And, it would be useful it you can reference the specific Bluetooth 5 profile that defines the feature, or perhaps the section of the Bluetooth spec.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 0):

They say that Bluetooth Hearing Aid Profile will support multi-user HQ audio and audio broadcast, but it is not adopted yet.